# Using true/real names and events in a fiction novel

Tags: fiction, legal

I would like to know where to reference what true or real names and events can be used in fiction novel.  Example:  Can you use words such as NFL or names of awards?  I understand you cannot use lyrics in songs but you can use titles (which are not copywrited).  Thanks for any help you can give me.

Comment: Debbie, we've closed this as a duplicate question, but if the question linked to above doesn't tell you what you need to know, please let us know why. We can edit and reopen this.